# Bootstrap 4 carousel with delayed video autoplay

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am trying to solve this problem. I have carousel with few video slides. When slide is loaded (active) I need that it will shows 3 seconds poster and after few seconds (for example 3s) it will play the video. I figured out how to make it for one slide, however I struggling to get working whole carousel.

HTML

```
<div class="my-1 my-lg-5">
  <div id="main_carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#main_carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#main_carousel" data-slide-to="1" ></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <video id="video_background" class="video-js vjs-16-9" poster="img/xxx.jpg" muted loop data-setup='{}'>
          <source src="xxx.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <video id="video_background" class="video-js vjs-16-9" poster="xxx.jpg" muted loop data-setup='{}'>
          <source src="xxx.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#main_carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#main_carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Working script for only one slide (any other slides cannot be in carousel)

```
let player = document.querySelector('#video_background');
player.addEventListener("canplay", function (){
        setTimeout(function(){
            player.play();
          }, 3000);

    })
```

Then I tried this for BS4 carousel, however it didn't work.

```
  $('#main_carousel').carousel({
    interval: 6000
  }).on('slide.bs.carousel',function(){
    var vids = $(this).find(".active video");
    setTimeout(function() {
             vids[0].play();
          }, 3000);
});
```

I would be glad for any help. Thank you.

Comment: Could you make demo may be will hel you.

Comment: here is working demo for one slide https://jsfiddle.net/mike90002/dsenazyL/7/